# Running MAMP with PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro, fpm

I'm using MAMP to develop locally on PHP. On my production server, I have PHP-FPM running so I can use things like `fastcgi_finish_request();`, etc.

For some reason, I just can't get it through my head how to get PHP-FPM running on MAMP. Is this even possible? As far as I can tell, FPM is included with PHP now...But looking through the files I don't see any kind of `php-fpm.conf` or any related files.

I've looked at so many things in the past couple of days trying to figure this out I don't know what to believe anymore...ha!

I'm running a simple test on `info.php`:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

phpinfo();
fastcgi_finish_request();
?>
```

Apologies for asking what is perhaps a silly question, I'm just spending way too much time on this.

Thanks!